# Deadlock when using SELECT FOR UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency, sql-update, deadlock

I noticed that concurrent execution of simple and identical queries similar to

```
BEGIN;  
SELECT files.data FROM files WHERE files.file_id = 123 LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE files SET ... WHERE files.file_id = 123;
COMMIT;
```

lead to deadlock which is surprising to me since it looks like such queries should not create a deadlock. Also: it is usually takes only milliseconds to complete such request. During such deadlock situation if I run:

```
 SELECT blockeda.pid AS blocked_pid, blockeda.query as blocked_query, 
 blockinga.pid AS blocking_pid, blockinga.query as blocking_query FROM pg_catalog.pg_locks blockedl
 JOIN pg_stat_activity blockeda ON blockedl.pid = blockeda.pid
 JOIN pg_catalog.pg_locks blockingl     ON(blockingl.transactionid=blockedl.transactionid
 AND blockedl.pid != blockingl.pid)
 JOIN pg_stat_activity blockinga ON blockingl.pid = blockinga.pid
 WHERE NOT blockedl.granted;
```

I see both of my identical select statements listed for `blocked_pid` and `blockin_pid` for whole duration of the deadlock.

So my question is: Is it normal and expected for queries that try to select same row `FOR UPDATE` to cause deadlock? And if so, what is the best strategy to avoid deadlocking in this scenario?

Comment: Can you post the `CREATE TABLE files`?

Comment: Questions like this need an exact table definition and the Postgres version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commands are contradicting.

If `files.file_id` is defined `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY KEY`), you don't need `LIMIT 1`. And you don't need explicit locking at all. Just run the `UPDATE`, since only a single row is affected in the whole transaction, there cannot be a deadlock. (Unless there are side effects from triggers or rules or involved functions.)

If `files.file_id` is not `UNIQUE` (like it seems), then the `UPDATE` can affect multiple rows in arbitrary order and only one of them is locked, a recipe for deadlocks. The more immediate problem would then be that the query does not do what you seem to want to begin with.

The best solution depends on missing information. This would work:

```
UPDATE files
SET    ...
WHERE  primary_key_column = (
         SELECT primary_key_column
         FROM   files 
         WHERE  file_id = 123
         LIMIT  1
     --  FOR    UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
         );
```

No `BEGIN;` and `COMMIT;` needed for the single command, while default auto-commit is enabled.

You might want to add [`FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` (or `FOR UPDATE NOWAIT`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE) to either skip or report an error if the row is already locked.

And you probably want to add a `WHERE` clause that avoids processing the same row repeatedly.

More here:

- [Postgres UPDATE … LIMIT 1](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/69497/3684)

Comment: Thank you for you answer @Erwin Brandstetter! The files table is indeed have multiple `UNIQUE` constraints and `SELECT` use all of them to uniquely identify single row. However the `UPDATE` statement _does not_ change any of fields that in unique constrain so i though that should make whole operation atomic.

Comment: Also: thank you for advice on using `UPDATE` with `WHERE` i though about that but in my case update logic is considerably more complicated and involved arbitrary  functions calls to calculate new file-data, so i can not put them into single SQL statement. I will try to refactor my code to use `files` primary key and see if that solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm... i refactored my code to use primary key for selecting row (and remove `LIMIT 1` as you suggested), but that did not solve the problem: I am still getting deadlocks. Any idea what else could be at play here? Thanks,

Comment: @Yatima: `my case ... involved arbitrary functions calls to calculate new file-data` The deadlock can happen there, too. Hard to guess without knowing the complete situation.

Comment: i was able to simply this and create much simpler test case. For clarity i moved this into separate question, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54317754/deadlock-when-using-select-for-update